Вычислить d, которое равно 1*2*3* и так до числа n, которое вводится пользователем
Вычислить d, которое равно 1 умножить на 2 умножить на 3 и так до числа n, которое вводится пользователем. Я написал так:
n=int(input())
p=1
s=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for b in range(1, i+1):
        p=p*b
    s=p
print(s)

Но этот код работает неправильно. Как исправить?

Что вы хотите узнать?

хочу узнать как написать код который вычисляет d, которое равно 1 умножить на 2 умножить на 3 и так до числа n, которое вводится пользователем

У вас уже почти готовый код, просто у вас один лишний вложенный цикл. Ваш код считает сумму таких произведений.

напишите готовый код, в этом выдается неправильный ответ

Вам же подсказали убрать один из циклов. Поработайте уже немного над логикой. И нужная величина называется факториал.

Если вы писали этот код, вы знаете как его доработать, убрать лишнее. Если вы этот код нашли, одолжили, позаимствовали, купили, то откройте учебник и научитесь программировать.

import math

N = int(input("Введите число: "))
print(f"Факториал {N}: {math.factorial(N)}")


Вы написали даже слишком сложно.
Вот так правильно:
n=int(input())
p=1  # (1)
for i in range(1,n+1):  # (2)
    p *= i  # (3)
print(p)



Задаём p равным 1.
Проходим по всем числам от 1 до n включительно.
Домножаем p на i


Ввод:

3

Вывод:

6


Автор вопроса ничего не писал и не хочет писать, он просто взял какой-то похожий код и просит его переделать в нужный ему )

@SwaD спасибо, исправил.

Я пишу ответы на эти школьные задачки постоянно. Автор вопроса не может и не хочет заниматься
информатикой - вопрос настолько простенький, что меня даже удивили старания на него ответить и  разбираться в каком-то коде, который не был и не будет эффективным, профессиональным и современным. Платить за решение задач неохота, вот и пробуют, авось проскочит. Проскочило. Я написал ответ, но по своим причинам. :-))))
